# Some of icons in react-icon are giving import error

Tags: reactjs

I installed *react-icons* and some icons like `FaBeer`, `FaBed` are working but many of them (`FaPencil`, `FaFloppyO`, `FaCalendarTimesO`) generate following error.
`./src/Note.js
Attempted import error:
'FaClose' is not exported from 'react-icons/fa'.`

1. Why I get this error?
2. Is there a premium (or something) version of *react-icons*?

PS: This is ReactJS project and I have a fresh install of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of [FontAwesome Icons](https://fontawesome.com) used in the current `react-icon` package is the `5.4.0` **free** version.  Some of the icons you may be trying to access are not available in that version.

For example, [`FaPencil`](https://fontawesome.com/icons/pencil?style=regular) is part of FontAwesome's **pro** package (paid version). You can, however, try `FaPencilAlt` instead - that one is available and working.

`floppy-o`, I believe, is a very old icon which has now been replaced in the current version with [`FaSave`](https://fontawesome.com/icons/save?style=regular), which is available in `react-icons`?

[`FaCalendarTimes`](https://fontawesome.com/icons/calendar-times?style=regular) is available as well, but not (any longer) `calendar-times-o`

The [list of free FontAwesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free) should be helpful for you to know which icons are available to you in `react-icons`.

---

If you'd like to bypass using `react-icons` and would instead like to use FontAwesome icons directly in your react project, then I would recommend using the [`react-fontawesome`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome) package. This allows you to add in free icons or also the pro icons (if you have paid for FontAwesome's pro package, that is). It also includes some functionality for customizing your icons which is specific to FontAwesome - this is functionality you wouldn't get in `react-icons`, which is working to provide a general all-purpose package for various icon packages.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting error because you're importing icons with wrong name.
For pencil it is `FaPencilAlt`

Check their official [website](https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/icons/fa) for more icons

```
import { FaBeer, FaPencilAlt, FaCalendarTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
```

Check this [Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/n92mmq73n0) link for other icons